# What is Ćuk converter's switch voltage stress?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I know voltage stress occurs during 1-D (switch off).

So voltage stress is going to be Vc1/(1-D).

But my professor said voltage stress is Vin + Vout because of charge balance law, but I didn't understand that.

[image]

Comment: In my experience, when talking about voltage stress on a part, you're referring to the *maximum* voltage the part will experience in normal operation. Time and duty cycle don't come into it at all. || Are you talking about the stress on the transistor, or on the capacitor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sry about that.I'm asking for mosfet switch's maximum voltage stress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peak voltage seen at the drain of a MOSFET in a Ćuk converter is approximated as the power supply voltage plus the magnitude of the output voltage plus one diode drop. For instance: -

[image]

So, my supply is 12 volt and the magnitude of the output voltage is 5.887 volts. This adds up to 17.887 volts. Add on the diode forward drop of 0.757 volts and you get 18.644 volts. This is 0.28 volts lower than the actual peak drain voltage of 18.924 volts.

Always choose a MOSFET rating that as about 1.5 times the expected peak value to cover uncertainties and mild circuit abuse. If you do this then the professors approximation is good enough.

And, always simulate this type of circuit to double check things.

Comment: Thank you sir, Can you tell me the simulation tool that you used, if you don't mind.

Comment: I used microcap.